# VS2022 - Enabling C++ Language Standard 20 and using CComPtr gives Cannot Convert error?

Tags: c++, c++20, atl, visual-c++-2022

I enabled language standard `ISO C++ 20 Standard` (needed for a new c++ source module) and received errors with some ATL items such as `CComPtr` and `CA2W`, I enabled `/permissive` but it still gives the errors.   I'm not sure how I fix the following:

```
CComPtr<IMsRdpDriveCollection>pdrivecolleciton=pnonscriptable->GetDriveCollection();

error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'IMsRdpDriveCollectionPtr' to 'ATL::CComPtr<IMsRdpDriveCollection>'
message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

And:

```
CString fn=CA2W(filename, CP_UTF8);

error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'ATL::CA2W' to 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>'
message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

How is this fixed?

TIA!!

Comment: No, this should not be C++20. If you compile that source file with C++17, does it change?

Comment: @273K It will compile at C++ 17 or lower, but I need C++20 because: `use of designated initializers requires at least '/std:c++20`

Comment: We need a [mcve].

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170): "The /permissive- option is implicitly set ... by the /std:c++20 option." and "The /permissive option must come after any option that sets /permissive- implicitly." You are setting /permissive too soon. You have to set it after setting C++20 mode. Once I do that, the code compiles (due to the permissiveness [allowing construction through *two* user-defined conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41594186)). Better would be to fix the code to be standard-conforming.

Comment: @RaymondChen I set the permissive option via the project settings option `Conformance mode` option (it's on the same Language option page where you choose the `C++ Language Standard`).   Should I just ignore that and manually added it to the command line?

Comment: If you go to the "Command Line" tab, you see that the options are given as `/JMC /permissive /GS /Wall /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Zc:inline /fp:precise /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++20 /FC /EHsc /nologo /diagnostics:column ` -- notice that `/permissive` came **before** `/std:c++20`. You have to manually add `/permissive` in the "Additional options" so it goes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to do it this way:

```
IMsRdpDriveCollection* prdpdcpptr=pnonscriptable->GetDriveCollection();
CComPtr<IMsRdpDriveCollection>pdrivecolleciton=prdpdcpptr;
```

and

```
CString fn;
fn=CA2W(filename, CP_UTF8);
```

The reason was posted in comments: [allowing construction through two user-defined conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41594186)